# prove :$\frac{36}{a^3+b^3}+11(a+b)\ge24+4\sqrt{3ab}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b\ge0: a+b>0$. Prove that: $$\frac{36}{a^3+b^3}+11(a+b)\ge24+4\sqrt{3ab}$$ When does equality hold?

I am stuck in this problem. Due to non-homogeneous inequality, I can not guess where is equality case.

I put $s=a+b; p=ab$ then we need to prove: $$\frac{36}{s^3-3ps}+11s\ge24+4\sqrt{3p}$$
But how should I finish the rest? Thanks for your help!

Edit: add more solutions

[image: Solution 1]
[image: Solution 2 part1][image: Sol 2 part2][image: Sol 2 part 3]

Here is my friend's solutions.

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use? Only basic algebra? Calculus? Convex optimization? Something else?

Comment: Anything which can help me. It is my teacher's problem for home work

Comment: If you put that into Wolfram, you'd get the equality condition.

Comment: How to use it dear friend?

Comment: If you're asking me how to use Wolfram to get the equality condition, please show your work (of using Wolfram) first, eg by showing the link of the equation that you typed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I continue your process. Let $m=\sqrt{3p},m=ks$ then the inequality become$$\frac{36}{s^3(1-k^2)}+(11-4k)s\ge24$$and accroding to the condition,we have$$0\leq k\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},s>0$$then we use the  AM–GM inequality$$\frac{36}{s^3(1-k^2)}+(11-4k)s/3+(11-4k)s/3+(11-4k)s/3\ge4 \sqrt[4]{\frac{36 (11-4 k)^3}{27 \left(1-k^2\right)}}$$for$$\frac{(11-4 k)^3}{1-k^2}$$It's not difficult to prove that it gets the minimum at $k=\frac{1}{2}$and so$$4 \sqrt[4]{\frac{36 (11-4 k)^3}{27 \left(1-k^2\right)}}\\\ge24$$so the inequality has been proved and when $$k=\frac{1}{2},s=2$$i.e$$\text{ab}=\frac{1}{3},a+b=2$$we obtain the equality case

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you find suitable terms for AM-GM inequality?

Comment: You need to elimilate the s^3，so divide the （11-4k）s to three parts is the most convient and direct way .Acctually It is just a try and it succeed